# Replace YouTube URL with Embed code in MySQL PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a column caled **meta_value** in table **wp_postmeta**

The column currently holds YouTube URLs, but we're trying to change the URL's to use the embed code. For instance:

**CURRENT VALUE**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHIhsLhQ-q8
```

**NEW VALUE SHOULD BE**

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZHIhsLhQ-q8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**This is my query but it doesn't seem to work for me:**

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET `meta_value`=REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'),'"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

**ERROR:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are closing the `REPLACE` function with a right paren just before "frameborder" and passing it 4 variables when it only accepts 3. See the documentation for [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace;).

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET `meta_value`= 
REPLACE( `meta_value`, 
         'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', 
         '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'),
         '"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' -- <- Invalid parameter
);
```

Unfortunately to do what you are trying to accomplish will require the use of regular expressions. You can accomplish this using the [mysql-udf-regex](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) user defined functions, however a likely easier solution would be to do a simple `SELECT` to get the `meta_values` that contain links to "youtube" and then do the replace with regular expressions in `PHP`.

Keep in mind that a lot of the `meta_values` in WordPress may be serialized, so a straight replace could break them. Using the [`get_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) and [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) will probably serve you better - not as fast but it makes sure nothing breaks in the conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some issues with your query... you've got an extra parameter on REPLACE, an extra paren... looks like you might have been on the right track but got mixed up.

You need to use CONCAT with REPLACE to get what you want. Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value=
    CONCAT(REPLACE(meta_value, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'), ' "frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

Basically, this query replaces meta_value with the correct string up to the end of the src, then concatenates the rest of the necessary string onto it, giving you the desired result.

Just as a final note, you might want to consider storing only the embed code, that is, just the "ZHIhsLhQ-q8" part... then utilize that however necessary when it is retrieved from the database. Might give you a little more freedom to use the Youtube video in a variety of different ways ... you can insert the embed code into a URL like you had before, or an iframe like your switching to... just a thought.